# What APIs exist to configure the speaker setup using C# in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, audio, driver

I've looked around many different places, but can't seem to find a straighforward way of doing this.

I have a number of sound cards in Windows 7 and output sound to my AVR amp using HDMI. The problem I have is that when the amp switches off, it causes windows to lose the speaker configuration.

So what I want to do is write a small utility that will reconfigure the speakers to be 5.1 surround sound. I'm sure there is a way to do it, but I've no idea where to start as there seem to be many different types of API.

Comment: I appear to have voted to close this in error, but I can find no way of undoing my mistake.  Sorry!

Comment: Can you describe how you currently do this manually?  There are some proprietary methods for certain sound devices, and rather than lead you down the wrong path, it would be helpful if you could be specific about what you do manually, and the expected outcome of your code.

Comment: Today I go to the system tray, right click on the speaker icon, click playback devices, then right click on the AVR (HDMI) device and select configure speakers, select 5.1, do next, next, next and it starts working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe nowadays these things are controlled via *Windows Core Audio* - one of the major new features of Windows Vista that nobody notices because it's almost entirely under the hood.

There is a .NET wrapper that claims to be stable: http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Nice library, but I'm still searching in the dark. Any clues on what to do?

Comment: @NickRandell I'm afraid I have no specific clues. Sorry, either SO decided not to notify me of your comment or I missed it.