# Change sample rate of audiocard with WasapiOut Naudio

Tags: c#, audio, device, naudio, sample-rate

I want to chose a specific sample rate for my audio card programmatically in c# with Naudio.
My output is a WasapiOut in exclusive mode.

I already tried a lot of things, but nothing worked and I've searched everywhere and I only found this : [How to Change Speaker Configuration in Windows in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391026/how-to-change-speaker-configuration-in-windows-in-c/41626709)
But they didn't really find a right solution.

Here's my WasapiOut :

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDevice device = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active).FirstOrDefault(d => d.DeviceFriendlyName == name);
outputDevice = new WasapiOut(device, AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, false,200);
```

What I don't understand is that here :
https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/WasapiOut.md
It says that :
"If you choose AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive then you are requesting exclusive access to the sound card. The benefits of this approach are that you can specify the exact sample rate you want"
And I didn't find anywhere how to specify the sample rate.

If someone here know the answer it would be great, thanks !

Edit :

I think I found a way by doing this :

```
var waveFormat5 = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(Int32.Parse(comboBox1.Text), 2);
            var test2 = new MixingSampleProvider(waveFormat5);
            var audioFile = new AudioFileReader("test.wav");
            var input = audioFile;
            test2.ReadFully = true;
            test2.AddMixerInput(new AutoDisposeFileReader(input,waveFormat5));
            outputDevice.Init(test2);
```

With "outputDevice" as my WasapiOut.
So I set the ouputDevice sample rate to the one that I chose with the Mixing Sample Provider and then I send an audiofile to that Mixer, is that the right way to do it ?
Because my audiofile sample rate is at 44100, and I chose to put my outputDevice sample rate to also 44100, but when I make outputDevice.Play(), the sound that I ear is faster than the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I used an AudioPlaybackEngine (https://markheath.net/post/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with) with a MixingSampleProvider, and a try/catch to handle the message error of "the inputs are not a the same sample rate".

Answer (score 1):

Once you've created an instance of `WasapiOut` you call `Init` passing the audio you want to play. It will try to use the sample rate (and `WaveFormat`) of that audio directly, assuming the soundcard supports it. Usi

Comment: Hey mark ! Thanks but I maybe didn't ask the right question. I want for example set the wasapiOut sample rate to 48000, even if I want to play an audio file at 44100. The outputDevice sample rate must stay the same as I chose, and the sample rate of the audio file must also stay the same as it was. I edited my question to add new information.